# Is the multiplicative order of a number always equal to the order of its multiplicative inverse?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is it true that $ord_{n}(a)=ord_{n}(\bar{a})$ $\forall n$?

Here, $\bar{a}$ refers to the multiplicative inverse of $a$ modulo $n$ and $ord_{n}(a)$ refers to the multiplicative order of $a$ modulo $n$.

Comment: Please define the notation that you're using.  What does $\bar a$ mean?  Does ord${}_n(a)$ mean the order of $a$ (in the multiplicative group) modulo $n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. Since $a \bar{a}=1$, it follows that for any positive integer $k$ we have $a^k (\bar{a})^k=1$. It follows that $a^k=1$ if and only if $(\bar{a})^k=1$. In particular, if $k$ is the smallest positive integer such that $a^k=1$, then $k$ is the smallest positive integer such that $(\bar{a})^k=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.

**Hint:** note that $a^m (\bar a)^n = a^{m-n}$.